# Batch convert fill and stroke colour of a set of icons

Tags: inkscape, icon, stroke, batch-processing, fill

I have a set of icons which are black and white. I want to try and make it shades of blue. Example is given below

[image]

I have set `stroke` and `fill` colours to it manually using Inkscape. Will it be possible to do the same for a no. of icons ( around 300 in a folder ) ? I use `alpha 156` for transparency in `fill` colour. Even a CLI tool will do. I tried `IcoMoon`, but not sure how to do it even though it has some option to change colours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SVG describes images using a text format, so you can simply open them in a text editor that allows replacing in multiple opened files (I use Sublime Text) and replace fill and stroke colors with your colors.

For example this image

[image]

is described like this:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="60" height="60" viewBox="0 0 60 60">
  <defs>
    <style>
      .cls-1 {
        fill: #e6e6e6;
      }

      .cls-1, .cls-2 {
        fill-rule: evenodd;
      }

      .cls-2 {
        fill: #0f32a4;
        stroke: #131313;
        stroke-width: 2px;
      }
    </style>
  </defs>
  <path id="Color_Fill_1" data-name="Color Fill 1" class="cls-1" d="M14.063,9.188L2.656,29.906,16.75,44.938,29,28.156Z"/>
  <path id="Color_Fill_2" data-name="Color Fill 2" class="cls-2" d="M34.646,13.063L19,33.333,29.667,51.667,45.333,37.333Z"/>
</svg>
```

if I change `fill` to red (`951c1c`), it'll become like this:

[image]

Comment: Many thanks. I will try with my file.